# Negative numbers in binary (8-bit)

Tags: binary, numbers, range, complement

I'm supposed to convert the following negative numbers to 8-bit binary using both (i) ones complement, and (ii) twos complement:

- -76
- -203
- -18
- -177

I know how to do -76 and -18...

•   -76

In binary (positive): 01001100
i) 10110011
ii) 10110100

•   -18

In binary (positive): 00010010
i) 11101101
ii) 11101110

But I don't know how to approach the other two since the range for 8 bits is -128 and 127... Heeelppp

Thanks in advance

Comment: the answer is in you question... (they are out of the range of 8 bits)

Comment: Safest is probably to state that they are out of range, and also give the lower 8 bits of performing a wider conversion (since this is something that can indeed happen, by oversight or occasionally by design)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to represent numbers beyond -128 to 127 in 8 bits. You need at least 9 bits to represent numbers in the range -256 to 255 using either one's complement or two's complement.